# Logging in All Controller and Class with .net Core SeriLog

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-file, serilog-aspnetcore

I was going to get some information about SeriLog from you.
I use it by integrating it on .net core application

```
var _logger= new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Debug()
    .WriteTo.File(@"C:\log\bis\processlog.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, fileSizeLimitBytes: null, retainedFileCountLimit: null, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
.CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.AddSerilog(_logger);
```

this is how i get information logs
Only to create a special log in the controller, it is necessary to add ILogger as a constructor on that controller.
without creating the constructor _logger.loginformation(""); How can I use it directly?